# Convert Matlab to OpenCV in python

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

I am trying to convert a piece of Matlab code to python using OpenCV package. But I don't know how to implement the filter2 in Matlab. Here is the matlab code.

```
imdist = imread("testimage1.bmp");
imdist = rgb2gray(imdist);
window = fspecial('gaussian',7,7/6);
window = window/sum(sum(window));
mu = filter2(window, imdist, 'same');
```

My python code is here:

```
import pyopencv as cv
import numpy as np
img = cv.imread("testimage1.bmp")
imdist = cv.Mat()
cv.cvtColor(img, imdist, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
row = cv.getGaussianKernel(7, 7.0/6.0)
col = cv.getGaussianKernel(7, 7.0/6.0)
window = cv.asMat(np.dot(col[:], row[:].T))
window = cv.asMat(window[:]/sum(sum(window[:])))
mu = cv.Mat()
# I'm not sure it should be filter2D
cv.filter2D(imdist, mu, -1, window)
```

The filter mask "window" are the same. But the variable "mu" is different from matlab result. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you've switched the anchor and kernel arguments around. Also, not sure why your anchor is 1D.

[The documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#cv.Filter2D) says the syntax is `cv.Filter2D(src, dst, kernel, anchor=(-1, -1))`, so I think you should be using `cv.filter2D(imdist, mu, window, (-1, -1))`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the cv here is pyopencv, and the document is cv2. The syntax here is correct.

Comment: I see. For reference, [this](http://pythonhosted.org/pyopencv/2.1.0.wr1.2.0/pyopencv-module.html#filter2D) would then be the relevant documentation.

Comment: I used filter2D as the API said. But the result is not what I want, just like the code above.

Comment: I realize that, I was just providing the link for anyone else who might be reading this. You could have mentioned pyopencv in your question btw, would have helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the official Python bindings, you can directly call [GaussianBlur](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#cv2.GaussianBlur) function:

```
dst = cv2.GaussianBlur(src, (7,7), 7.0/6.0)
```

or use `cv2.Smooth` function with `CV_GAUSSIAN` which internally calls the same.